# How to select URLs in gnome-terminal without using the mouse?

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal

`gnome-terminal` supports copying and opening URLs (in the default system browser). Unfortunately the feature seems to only work with a mouse, as a keyboard-only user I keep copying the strings to the `tmux` clipboard, then run a command to open the webpage in a browser.

Gnome has an accessibility setting called 'mouse keys' which allows moving the cursor with keyboard, but enabling the option disables the standard numpad functionality and at least on higher resolutions the movement speed is low. The best solution would perhaps be  tracking the terminal cursor location and mapping the context menu (pictured below) to [the menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key).

[image: screenshot]